# How to count the number of users registered per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

A car driver get registered on different checkpoints in the street. I want to check how many times per day in a  week a driver has been registered.

So what I have so far is this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Register.userId AS "Active Users" Register.timestamp 
  FROM [dbo].[Register]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users]
  ON Register.userId = Users.id AND Register.organisationId = users.organisationId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Organisations]
  ON Register.organisationId = Organisations.id
  where Organisations.id = '1105'  AND (log.timestamp between '2014-10-1 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-7 23:59:59') 
Group by Register.userId, Register.timestamp
```

What I want to find out is how many times per week does the user drives the car. The user can register many times per one day in different checkpoint but I am interested in only one registration that shows that that user used the car on that particular day.

Comment: if you can include sample data and expected result, then you can improve your chance to get nice answer

Comment: What does "how many times per day in a week" mean?  Sample data is so important.

Comment: Sorry, I will modify my question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assuming you need your data group by

1. User
2. Week
3. Day (once per day)

SELECT Register.userId AS "Active Users" DatePart(week, Register.timestamp) WeekNum, Count(DISTINCT Convert(date, Register.timestamp)) RegCountPerDay 
  FROM [dbo].[Register]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users]
  ON Register.userId = Users.id AND Register.organisationId = users.organisationId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Organisations]
  ON Register.organisationId = Organisations.id
  where Organisations.id = '1105'  AND (log.timestamp between '2014-10-1 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-7 23:59:59') 
Group by Register.userId, DatePart(week, Register.timestamp), Count(DISTINCT Convert(date, Register.timestamp))
```

Comment: I get this error:
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just needed to remove the Count part on the GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Register.userId AS "Active Users", Register.timestamp,
  Count(Register.timestamp)
  FROM [dbo].[Register]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users]
  ON Register.userId = Users.id AND Register.organisationId = users.organisationId
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Organisations]
  ON Register.organisationId = Organisations.id
  where Organisations.id = '1105'  
        AND (log.timestamp between '2014-10-1 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-7 23:59:59') 
Group by Register.userId, Register.timestamp
```

Comment: you don't need register.timestamp in select and group by.

Comment: @radar:- yes, I think also, but OP has in question, then I let it be

Comment: From this query I get the all the registrations of the users per one week. I want to get the count of how many days did the user use the car per week.